# Выбор движка для 2D игра на Android

Tags: framework, android

Работаю Android программистом уже 3 месяца, на работе для приложений хватает и NDK, но недавно решил сделать свою игру, без замудреностей. Начал делать, и появилась проблема, графика оказалась слишком тяжелой, и появилась нужда в использовании framework`a. Мне один товарищ посоветовал [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) , он с ним работал, и он ему очень понравился. Но Starling работает на Flash, а ни для кого не секрет, что это умирающая технология. 
Так вот, какой framework лучше выбрать? Я конечно слышал, и читал про libGDX, Cocos 2D и т.д. , но кто то хвалит, кто то нет, может кто то подскажет наилучший framework по производительности, низкому порогу вхождения и т.д. 
Знаю Java, если фреймворк будет работать полностью на нем, то хорошо, а если нет, то выучить новый язык программирования я не против.

Comment: Я уже лет десять слышу, что флэш - умирающая технология. Многие технологии позавидовали бы столь долгому и плодотворному "умиранию".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 2):

Я юзал LibGDX. Для простых игр его советую. Хотя, на нём можно и сложные игры создавать.

[Lode Runner](http://lode-runner.suvitruf.ru/) и [Bomberman](http://suvitruf.ru/bomberman-na-android/) я на нём писал. Простой движок. Если интересно, шарил полностью сорсы [Bomberman'а](https://github.com/Suvitruf/libgdx/tree/master/NES%20Bomberman).  Если нужны туториалы, то [вот](http://suvitruf.ru/libgdx/), парочка моих статей по движку.

Answer (score 1):

мне понравилась Shiva. Для 2d/3d самое то для игр.

[Сюда](http://www.shivaengine.com)

Answer (score 1):

Выбрал для себя Corona SDK, всем спасибо!